# How to programmatically modify connection string?

Tags: .net, mysql, vb.net, visual-studio

I am working in visual studio with a datagridview that is bound to a mysql database via the .net mysql connector. In my vb app I have some text fields that provide the necessary fields for building the connection string which I have defined as:

```
Dim connectionString As String = "server=" + sqlHost.Text + ";User Id=" + sqlUser.Text + ";password=" + sqlPassword.Text + ";database=some_database;Persist Security Info=True"
```

So I was wondering how I can programmatically set the connection string to the string defined in the code above. Also I know storing this information this way is a security threat so anyway ways to secure the connection string would be most helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As to your main question, I have no idea what you are actually asking. The code you gave *is* programmatically setting the connection string.  What more do you want?

Comment: Are you asking how to programmatically modify the web.config to store the string?  The code you have builds one, just use that in your mysql connector.

Comment: Siride I apologize that I have not explained myself well enough. However the code I gave does not programmatically set the connection string but rather defines a buffer with the connection string. The connector knows nothing of this string. Initially I used the data source configuration wizard to specify the connection string. However what I am trying to do is change this connection string to the string defined in the code I presented via vb code and not the configuration wizard. I hope this explains it a little clearer. Thank you for taking interest in helping me, it is most appreciated.

Comment: I dont know what is the real question but maybe SqlConnectionStringBuilder is what you want.

Comment: Have you tried setting the connectionString on the DataSource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I used the data source configuration wizard to specify the connection string

When you use the wizard Visual Studio makes a whole bunch of choices for you. Assuming you chose dataset  the connection string was stored in the app.config connectionstrings section. In the dataset's XSD a Global.YourNameSpace.My.MySettings.Default.YourDataSetConnectionString is set to the appsettings key.

This is why its hard to find it if you don't know where to look. There are a lot of ways to change the connection, but one way is...

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

     'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'MusicDataSet.music_file' table. You can move,   or remove it, as needed.
    Me.Table1_TableAdapter.Connection = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection("server=" + sqlHost.Text + ";User Id=" + sqlUser.Text + ";password=" + sqlPassword.Text + ";database=some_database;Persist Security Info=True" )

    Me.Table1TableAdapter.Fill(Me.MyDataSet.Table1)


 End Sub
```

As for securing the strings you can use the built in [encryption technology](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89211k9b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: This worked. Also thank you for the encryption documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this - you already have the actual string for the connection string in the code you posted - all you need to do is use it for an actual sql connection

```
Public Sub ConnectToSql()
Dim conn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
Dim connectionString As String = "server=" + sqlHost.Text + ";User Id=" + sqlUser.Text + ";password=" + sqlPassword.Text + ";database=some_database;Persist Security Info=True"
conn.ConnectionString = connectionString 
Try
    conn.Open()
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show("Failed to connect to data source")
Finally
    conn.Close()
End Try
```

End Sub